# Does GCC have a pragma to enforce auto-vectorization?

Tags: c++, multithreading, gcc, vectorization, auto-vectorization

I'd like to write some code which can be vectorized and I'd like to know that it stays that way. Does GCC have such a check? I saw that LLVM has one (that generates a warning anyway).

Comment: `#pragma GCC optimize`?

Comment: what does the warning/error look like if it was unable to vectorize it?

Comment: AFAIK, you can hint to GCC that this can be vectorized, but you can't force it

Comment: It's an old answer and I'm not sure if it's still relevant. It basically says no. There's no way to assert that vectorization occurred.

Comment: there's no pragma but you can tell gcc to print auto-vectorization "warnings" with `-fopt-info-vec-missed`. [Why doesn't GCC show vectorization information?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68719306/995714)